# ASP Alert text before invoke onClick method

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Basically I have a button and a corresponding onClick method as below:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="button_short" Text="SAVE & SUBMIT" OnClick="BtnSave_Click"></asp:Button>

protected void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {...}
```

Now I just want to have a javaScript `confirm` when the button being click but I've no idea how will it trigger the `BtnSave_Click` method right after user click "OK"

Comment: use onclientClick event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="button_short" Text="SAVE" 
   OnClick="BtnSave_Click" onClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
  </asp:Button>.
```